# what's the hidden item in the array when clipboard content is split

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following three cells in Excel :

```
a
b
c
```

I then copy them into the clipboard and carry out the following script in C#. The resulting array has 4 members. Why?

```
string s = Clipboard.GetText();
string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the array's items to see what it contains? That would yield a clue.

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the value of the items in the array.  Perhaps there is a new line character after the "c"

Comment: What does `s.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` return?

Comment: @PaulSasik outputting was my problem - because it was "\n" at the end it wasn't visible when I was outputting to a label.

Comment: @SteveDog thanks - I just followed my nose and looked at one of the IDE features that lets me inspect the elements. "\n" tagged on the end.

Comment: @TimSchmelter +1 - thanks for putting me onto this overloaded split option - ended up using `s.Split(new string[] { "\n","\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) by `\r\n`, you can also use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx):

```
s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: crafty - +3 for your comment and now I'm marking this as the answer! :). I'm still in pain after getting -3 for the question!

Comment: The comments don't count and i don't see -3 ;)

Comment: thanks for help - these overloaded methods make c# ridiculously large - I'm a fascinated newbie; getting addicted